# Get the lines from textarea and insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, textarea

I've been trying to add multiple rows to mysql using textarea.
The thing is that i can get all the lines from the textbox but 
i want to separate them into values using " | " as a separator.

```
                    $invalid = 0;
                    $inserted = 0;
                    $totalaccounts = 0;
                    $lista = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['textarea']);
                    $price = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
                    $lines = explode("\n", $lista);
                    while($lines){
                    foreach($lines as $line) {
                        $lines1 = explode(" | ", $line);
                        foreach($lines1 as $line1) {
                            $line1 = $db->real_escape_string($line1);
                            if($line1 == ""){
                                $line1 = "NONE";
                            }
                            unset($line1);
                        }
                        // SQL CHECK IF DUPLICATED $lines1[0] $lin....
                        $numrowz = mysqli_num_rows($sqlz);
                        if($numrowz >= 1) {
                            echo 'DUPLICATED: ' . $line1 . '<br />';
                            $invalid++;
                        }else{
                            // SQL INSERT CODE
                            $inserted++;
                        }   
                    }
                    }
                echo 'Total Accounts: ' . $inserted . '<br />';
                echo 'Total Duplicated/Expired: ' . $invalid . '<br />';
                echo 'Total Inserted: ' . $inserted . '<br /><br />';

                echo '<html><body><a href="continue.html">CLICK HERE TO CONTINUE</body></html>';
                }
```

This is the code im using, but i get unlimited Duplicated inputs by just trying to add one.
Need help :(

Comment: I think you just have to remove the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. `while($lines)` will continue to run as long as `$lines` [evaluates to true](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), and I'm not seeing anywhere in your code where the control variable($lines) is unset or set to false.

I'm also not seeing anywhere that you would benefit from such a while loop, because you're already looping through the `$lines` array. It seems like you meant to do a conditional, such as `if ($lines) {` instead.

Comment: I removed the loop, it works inserting only the first line.
I want to insert multiple lines, how can i do it ?